# Leap year while-loop

Tags: python

I'm having problems. Basically the code won't let me add a year after the user submits a year to check if it's a leap year. If it is a leap year, the loop stops, if not I need to add a year and give me the leap year. How can I improve it?

```
year = int(input("Year:"))

while True:
    leapyear = year+1
    if leapyear%4 == 0 and leapyear%100 != 0 or leapyear%100 == 0 and leapyear%400 == 0:
        break

if True:
    print(f"The next leap year after {year} will be {leapyear}")
```

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `leapyear = year+1` you do not increase it, if `year=2013`, the loop will make `leapyear = 2013+1 = 2014` every time, you need to increase `leapyear`

```
year = 2016
leapyear = year

while True:
    if leapyear % 4 == 0 and leapyear % 100 != 0 or leapyear % 100 == 0 and leapyear % 400 == 0:
        break
    leapyear += 1

print(f"The next leap year after {year} will be {leapyear}")
```

You can shorten `while` + `if/break` in one statement

```
while not (leapyear % 4 == 0 and leapyear % 100 != 0 or leapyear % 100 == 0 and leapyear % 400 == 0):
    leapyear += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

As azro pointed out, `leapyear` will only ever equal `year + 1`, and to make it increase you could do `leapyear = leapyear + 1`.

Also in the code you provided you are checking if the year **after** the year inputted by the user is a leapyear. If you intended to check the current year as well, you should do the if statement first before increasing leapyear.

```
if True:
```

This will always run, so you might as well not include it.